# How to make Java program wait while a listener is working?

Tags: java, listener, jslider

I have a JSlider in my program. Program does something when the value of slider is changed. What I want to do is to increase the value of slider until its max value and I need to wait every time slider value is increased for the things that I do in the ChangeListener class.

Here is my related codes (svPlay is like a play button):

```
this.svPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i=slider.getValue()+1;i<=slider.getMaximum();i++){
                slider.setValue(i);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is, for example if i=10, then program waits 10*1000(milisecond that I used with sleep() method) and it does all the changeListener jobs at the same time.

After slider.setValue(i), changeListener must work and then program should sleep for 1000 ms. How can I do that?

Edit: This is how I changed my program, according to above code. But now nothing is happening when slider value is changed and slider "freezes".

```
this.slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        Thread.sleep(1234);
                        if(checkBox.isSelected()){
                            CyApplicationManager manager = adapter.getCyApplicationManager();
                            CyNetworkView networkView = manager.getCurrentNetworkView();
                            CyNetwork network = networkView.getModel();
                            CyTable table = network.getDefaultNodeTable();
                            FilterUtil filter = new FilterUtil(network,table);
                            ArrayList<CyNode> activities = filter.FilterRowByNodeType("activity", "nodeType");

                            CyColumn timeColumn = table.getColumn("startTime"); // Getting start time column
                            List<String> timeList = filter.getTimeFromColumn(timeColumn); // Gets value of start time column without null value
                            sliderVisualization.sortActivityTimes(timeList, activities);
                            sliderLabel.setText(timeList.get(slider.getValue()));
                            sliderVisualization.hideFutureNodes(timeList, filter, network, networkView);
                            networkView.updateView();
                        }
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();

        }
    });

    this.svPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                slider.setEnabled(false);
                for(int i=slider.getValue()+1;i<=slider.getMaximum();i++){
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        slider.setValue(i);
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                slider.setEnabled(true);
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

I put if statement before and after Thread.sleep() in addChangeListener method but both way did not worked. I do not know if I convert it well or not. Can you help through this code please?

Comment: It's not clear for me what exactly you want to achieve. Also sleeping for arbitrary amount of time because you are waiting for what I assume something to be done on different thread is bad approach. You'd be better off with using `wait` inside svPlay listener, and `notify` inside the slider listener.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I tryed both notify and notifyAll but it did not worked. This time the things that is inside of the slider changed listener works only I click the svPlay button. Simply I want that: Program should wait for 1 second after every time slider value is changed and slider changed listener is worked. How can I do that?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Actually I tryed to convert this code to my program but I could not make it. Can you look at the next answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understand from your question: you have long calculations going on in Slider change listener. You want to perform calculations for a range of values, and reflect that on the slider.

If the above premise is correct, you don't want to sleep n seconds while calculations are going on -- you want to wait for them to finish and proceed asap. One way to do it, is using wait and notify commands on a lock (note, that recent Java comes with java.util.concurrent package, which contains higher level multithreading control and I think would be better to use, however I'm not familiar with it myself)

```
package testas;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Slider {

    static class View {

        public JPanel panel;
        public JSlider slider;
        public JButton button;
        public JTextField tf;

        public View() {
            panel = new JPanel();
            button = new JButton("a");
            slider = new JSlider();
            tf = new JTextField(4);
            panel.add(button);
            panel.add(slider);
            panel.add(tf);
        }


    }

    static class Controller {

        private Object lock;
        private View view;

        public Controller() {
            lock = new Object();
        }

        private synchronized void buttonHandler() {
            new Thread(() -> {
                view.slider.setEnabled(false);
                for(int i=view.slider.getValue()+1;i<=view.slider.getMaximum();i++){
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        view.slider.setValue(i);
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                view.slider.setEnabled(true);
            }).start();
        }

        private synchronized void sliderChangeHandler(int value) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        Thread.sleep(1234);//some long calculations
                        view.tf.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }).start();
        }

        public void setView(View v) {

            view = v;
            v.button.addActionListener(l -> buttonHandler());
            v.slider.addChangeListener(l -> {
                JSlider slider = (JSlider) l.getSource();
                if (!slider.getValueIsAdjusting())
                    sliderChangeHandler(slider.getValue());
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Controller c = new Controller();
            View v = new View();
            c.setView(v);
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.add(v.panel);
            f.pack();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you understand corretly. I am sure this code can solve my problem. But there are so much concept that I have not used before. I am trying to find a way to adapt this code to my program. Thank you so much for your answer.